# Flutter : How check if List contain passes item?

Tags: list, flutter, object

I have method when icon on pressed ,

```
onPressed: () {
          check(snapshot.data[index]);
        },
```

and method to check if the data found on another list ,I did as below :

```
    void add_cart(item){
    for (var x in list){
      if (x.id==item.id){
        cartCount = 1;
      }
      else {
        cartCount = 0;
      }
    }

    if (cartCount == 1){
      list.remove(item);
    }
    else{
      list.add(item);
    }
    print(cartCount);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

### the cartcount work correct but remove method don't work , what is the true way for that ?

Comment: Did you misspelled the llist (double ll) . In your code above list.remove(item); is different than llist.add(item);

Comment: @bluenile I will update it just min

Comment: @bluenile I changed some thing

Comment: Put your item model code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override `==` and `hashcode` of your cart model like this

```
class CartModel {
  String id;

  // other properties

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) => other is CartModel && runtimeType == other.runtimeType && id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

after that `list.remove(item);` will work as intended